# Defer dropping a temporary table in MySQL with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to solve a performance issue where we are running a WHERE IN clause on a ton of non-sequential IDs. According to [this](https://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/) and the Performance MySQL book, you can speed up performance by creating a temporary table with the field in question and joining on the table you care about.

I have the following Rails code within an `ActiveRecord::Base` class:

```
def self.where_in(field, ids)
  tmp_table = "tmp_table_#{SecureRandom.uuid.gsub('-', '_')}"
  begin
    # Create temporary table with one column
    connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #{tmp_table} (param INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=Memory")

    # Insert ids into the table (doesn't have to be ids)
    vals = ids.map{|i| "(#{i})"}.join(", ")
    connection.execute("INSERT INTO #{tmp_table} (param) VALUES #{vals};")

    # Return the join relation which is the same as WHERE IN (...)
    return self.joins("INNER JOIN #{tmp_table} on #{field} = #{tmp_table}.param").all
  ensure
    # Drop table after we're done...this is the problem
    connection.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS #{tmp_table}")
  end
end
```

But the problem is that this creates a SQL statement dependent on the existence of a temporary table that I'm dropping in the ensure statement. If I remove the ensure statement, it works fine however the temporary table still exists.

In light of this, my question is this:

**How would I "defer" the dropping of this table short of popping the table name onto a background worker to drop at a later time?**

OR

**Would I be safe to NOT drop the table and just assume the connection pool will reap the connection, thereby dropping the table eventually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after quite a bit of research, I answered my own questions:

1. There is no way to defer the dropping of the table, however, I was able to force the relation to execute the query now using the `ActiveRecord::Relation#load` method.
2. In our application (and I'm sure many others) we cache connections for later use and rarely recycle them, so NOT dropping the table would be a very obvious memory leak.

I ended up coding this method up in a `Util` class instead of AR base:

```
def self.where_in(collection, field, params)
  tmp_table = "tmp_table_#{SecureRandom.uuid.gsub('-', '_')}"
  collection.connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #{tmp_table} (param INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=Memory")

  vals = params.map{|i| "(#{i})"}.join(", ")
  collection.connection.execute("INSERT INTO #{tmp_table} (param) VALUES #{vals};")

  records = collection.joins("INNER JOIN #{tmp_table} on #{field} = #{tmp_table}.param").load

  yield records if block_given?

  collection.connection.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS #{tmp_table}")
  return records.to_a
end
```

The problem turned up when I benchmarked and disproved my premise that this method would actually be faster. I used the following benchmark code:

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 1000.times { Thing.where(id: refs).count } }
  x.report { 1000.times { Util.where_in(Thing, :id, refs) {|o| o.count }}}
end
```

And the results were pretty bad:

```
   user     system      total        real
0.940000   0.050000   0.990000 (  1.650669)
8.950000   0.260000   9.210000 ( 12.201616)
```

Due to MySQL caching, the method I tried is substantially slower over multiple iterations. There are probably other benchmarks I could try but it currently seems like this optimization is not worth it.

Oh well `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`